# Reified argument bounds not checked

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

Why does the below code compile?

Inside `SomeScope.getEntity()`:

`get<Entity>()` clearly violates the bounds of the `get()` function.
But if you omit `<Entity>` (which you can because of return type inference) the code compiles.

```
interface EntityBase
interface Entity

class SomeScope {
    inline fun <reified T : EntityBase> get(): T {
        return "whatever" as T  // doesn't matter
    }
}

fun SomeScope.getEntity(): Entity {
    return get() // get<Entity>() wouldn't compile
}
```

Comment: It's a bug in the compiler. I suggest you report it on YouTrack. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-54964/Reified-type-argument-bounds-not-checked